# PHP upload script not functioning and no error on apache logs

Tags: php, upload

I created an upload script using the resources from tizag, the script is returning an onscreen error however no error in the apache logs.

HTML Form

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="90000000" />
  Select video to upload:
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br /> 
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" /> 
   </form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$target_path = "/var/www/html/upload/";
$target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0] );
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] [0],        $target_path))
 { 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadefile']['name'] [0]). " has been      uploaded"; 
  } 
  else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
  }
  ?>
```

This shouldn't be very hard to impliment, but with no errors on apache it's very hard for me to troubleshoot. My php knowlegdge is limited so please bare that in mind.

Kind Regards,

Mark Couto

Comment: What is the onscreen error?

Comment: The echo return: Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: In most cases this can mean a permissions error for the directory. Set error reporting on for detailed error in php using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the code

Comment: I'd try and remove `[0]` in all of those. That's usually if you have more than one file. It's worth a shot and check for folder permissions.

Comment: Ok, completed. Saved the file still the same issue after running the form.
The folder is also 777

Comment: Show us what the "onscreen error" is exactly.

Comment: After removing the `[0]` i know have the following errors, which don't make much sense.
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 4

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpensZRS' to '/var/www/html/upload/' in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 4`

Comment: Ok, then instead of `$target_path = "/var/www/html/upload/";` try `$target_path = "upload/";` if running your script from the root and that the upload folder is just outside the root. Your folder needs proper write permissions also.

Comment: @Fred -ii the error was => `echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file`

Comment: Ok, changed to `$target_path = "upload/";` still the same error.

Comment: Ok I think I know. This `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] [0],        $target_path))` should be `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] [0],        $target))` - maybe even remove the `[0]` as previously stated. Try that. You're calling the wrong variable.

Comment: Can you post a var_dump of $_FILES before move_uploaded_file.

Comment: Wait, I'm wrong about my previous comment; scratch that. Or maybe not. Did you try it?

Comment: @fred -ii- i removed the `[0]` as previously said however have not tried `$target` not `$target_path` So will give that a shot now.

@ Dragonyen- not sure how to execute that.

Comment: `$target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0] );` to `$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0] );` - The Tizag tutorial doesn't change their variables. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: @fred -ii- That worked :D, although had a spelling error `'uploadefile'`

Thanks guys for all your help.

Comment: Great! Shall I post an answer to close 'er up? I'll include the typo.

Comment: If you like ! Thanks for all your help i'm now going to devlope hat basic code into bigger and better things !

Comment: You're welcome, glad this was resolved. (done).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
$target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0] );
```

As it stands, `$target` is just a stray variable and not being used anywhere else.

It should read as:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][0] );
```

> *"I created an upload script using the resources from tizag"*

The Tizag tutorial you followed doesn't change their variables.

Their example:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

- Source: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Plus, you have a typo in `['uploadefile']` which should read as `['uploadedfile']`

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that php is configured to allow file upload.
in your "php.ini" file search for the directive, and set it ON,

> ```
> file_uploads= ON
> ```

**Source** :  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @markjose your code is working fine for me, I think there is something wrong with the $path, can you show us your directory structure?

Comment: Fixed it ! 
I was using `target_path` instead of `target` and had a spelling error `uploadefile` not `uploadedfile`

Comment: Glad to hear that! you must thank fred ,He played an unique role in figuring this out..